# Instantiate Prefab at position of parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I am trying to instantiate a prefab as a child, and I want it's location to be the exact same as it's parent. Somehow the prefab is not instantiated on the exact same position.

The parent is also a child of another object. For clarity:

[image: Object Structure]

"Selectable(Clone)" is the instantiated prefab. I want the position to be the same as the "Lader" position.

My Code:

```
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
        obj.transform.parent = parent.transform;
        obj.transform.localPosition = position;
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using the overload of `Instantiate` that takes a `Transform` (and a position and rotation)?

Comment: @UnholySheep That was my first try, but no succes unfortunately.

Comment: transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero; (After instantiating and assigning the parent)

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what you're looking for. Make sure both child and parent pivots are centered.

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
obj.transform.SetParent(parent, false);
```

Comment: Alternatively, `Instantiate(prefab, parent.transform, false);` which also avoids a recalc on the transform hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the position before setting the parent?

```
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
    obj.transform.Position = parent.transform.position;
    obj.transform.parent = parent.transform;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
obj.transform.position = parent.transform.position;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. You either need to assign transform.position equal to parent's position or localPosition = zero

Comment: Yep I assign transform.position equal to parent's position. What is wrong?

Comment: You are assigning transform.localPosition equal to parent's transform.position. You are essnetially adding the radius vector of parent gameobject to itself. So if the parent is on (1, 0, 0) coordinates your answer will place the object at (2, 0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are not specifying that the new GameObject is to be a child of anything, so be sure to do this.

```
public GameObject parentLadder;
public GameObject prefab
```

Next, don't call a variable position, as it's already a unity global.

```
Vector3 pos = (0,0,0)
```

Then actually instantiate our object and set it to parent transform.

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    obj.transform.position = parentLadder.transform.position;
    obj.transform.localPosition = pos;
```

Comment: Well, technically everything is right, but you are assigning the same position twice. Either use the overloaded Instantiate and pass parent's position and rotation (prefab, parentLadder.transform.position, parentLadder.transform.rotation) or Instantiate the prefab and than zero localPosition and localRotation with Vector3.zero and Quaternion.identity;

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate direct the child transform using the Instantiate()

**try:**

```
Instantiate(GameObeject, transformPosition, Quaternion.identity, transformParent);
```

**Exemple:**

```
Instantiate(popUpMsg, Canvas.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, Canvas.transform);
```

Now PopUp GameObject is Canvas' child